# Is there a way to access the defines in a VS Code c_cpp_properties.json file from a Makefile?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, visual-studio-code

I'm starting to experiment with VS Code on Linux and trying to build a C++ project. The project contains a bunch of source files and a Makefile. To define C/C++ macros for IntelliSense, VS Code supports the attribute `"defines"` in the file called c_cpp_properties.json.

Unfortunately, after searching a lot, I couldn't find how to access those `"defines"` macros from a Makefile in order to use the same set of macros when editing the code and when building it. I am trying to avoid having to manually edit both the Makefile and the JSON file separately whenever I need to adjust a macro.

Answer (score 0):

[gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) is a GNUmake library which allows enough programmatic make to attack such problems:

If the json file looks like this:

```
{
  "env": {
    "myDefaultIncludePath": ["${workspaceFolder}", "${workspaceFolder}/include"],
    "myCompilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/gcc-7"
  },
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Mac",
      "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
      "includePath": ["${myDefaultIncludePath}", "/another/path"],
      "macFrameworkPath": ["/System/Library/Frameworks"],
    "defines": ["FOO", "BAR=100", "BAZ = \"some string with spaces [brackets] and quotes\""],
      "forcedInclude": ["${workspaceFolder}/include/config.h"],
      "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
      "cStandard": "c11",
      "cppStandard": "c++17",
      "compileCommands": "/path/to/compile_commands.json",
      "browse": {
        "path": ["${workspaceFolder}"],
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
        "databaseFilename": ""
      }
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

Then the following make file will isolate the defines and their values:

```
include gmtt/gmtt.mk

c_cpp_properties.json := $(file <c_cpp_properties.json)

# the glob pattern uses [[] and []] to catch the square brackets
parsed_json := $(call glob-match,$(c_cpp_properties.json),*"defines": [[]*[]]$(comma)$(newline)*)

defines := $(word 4,$(parsed_json))

# first save all escaped quotes by converting them to the -never-matching character:
defines := $(subst \",$(-never-matching),$(defines))

# all quotes which are left are separators now, replace with space:
defines := $(subst ",$(space),$(defines))

# get rid of spaces and commas between defines: remove any number of leading or trailing space-replacements
# and finally convert back the escaped quotes to their now non-escaped ("\" removed) form:
$(call while,$$(or $$(findstring $$(space)$$(-spacereplace),$$(defines)),\
                   $$(findstring $$(-spacereplace)$$(space),$$(defines))),\
     defines := $$(subst $$(space)$$(-spacereplace),$$(space),$$(subst $$(-spacereplace)$$(space),$$(space),$$(defines))),\
  defines := $$(subst $$(-never-matching),",$$(subst $$(space)$$(comma)$$(space),$$(space),$$(defines))))

# Print what we have so far:
$(info --------------$(newline)$(defines)$(newline)-------------)

# for each item in $(defines): split at ":", then reverse the space-replacement and print them
$(foreach d,$(defines),$(info define-name:$(call spc-unmask,$(firstword $(subst =, ,$(d))))  define-content: $(call spc-unmask,$(word 2,$(subst =, ,$(d))))$(newline)))
```

Output:

```
$ make
--------------
 FOO BAR=100 BAZ§=§"some§string§with§spaces,§[brackets]§and§quotes"
-------------
define-name:FOO  define-content:

define-name:BAR  define-content: 100

define-name:BAZ   define-content:  "some string with spaces, [brackets] and quotes"
```

The one caveat is that the glob pattern to dissect the file is critical to well-formedness of the json file - the end of the `"defines"` line *must* end with `],\n`, though you can play around with optional characters `?` but this has a natural end with glob patterns which are not as powerful as REs.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to access the defines in a VS Code c_cpp_properties.json file from a Makefile?

Not that I know, but there is a way to do it the other way around, and that's what you should do anyway (configure your build and make your developer tooling understand your build configuration instead of the other way around, which is a bit more portable).

Define your macros in your Makefile and use [the Microsoft Makefile Tools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.makefile-tools) (I have no affiliation) as your configuration provider instead of using c_cpp_properties.json directly. See [the VS Code C++ FAQ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp#_how-do-i-get-intellisense-to-work-correctly) and `configurationProvider` in [the c_cpp_properties.json docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference). It should be analogous to https://stackoverflow.com/a/77079021/11107541. I.e. putting `"C_Cpp.default.configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.makefile-tools",` in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) (I'd advise in the workspace settings.json file instead of the user settings.json file).