# How can I make the VS Code clangd extension aware of the include paths defined in my CMake configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, clangd

I'm coding C++ on a Raspberry Pi 3B via VSCode's remote ssh. Currently, I just manually add all extra include directories (and other compiler settings) in `settings.json`:

```json
{
    "clangd.fallbackFlags": [
        "-I/usr/include/foo",
        "-I/usr/include/bar",
        "-I${workspaceFolder}/src",
        "-std=c++17"
    ]
}
```

And I'm seeking for an automated way to do that.

I'm **NOT** using the `CMake Tools` and `IntelliSense` plugin, as it is very CPU and memory consuming, almost exhaust RPi's 1GB memory. In contrast, `clangd` is much lighter and capable by a RPi.