# How do I open a large existing CMake project into Visual Studio Code on MacOS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I want to use Visual Studio Code to edit, navigate, and debug a large CMake based C++ project, with many subdirectories and imported conan based packages.

All the docs I have found are for a trivial case of creating a new "hello world" project.

Ideally I could point it to a build folder generated by the Project Root (as [ProjectRoot]/build and the [ProjectRoot]/CmakeLists.txt (build generated with -G "unix makefiles")

And have it pull in all the proper include directories for intellisense C++, and load it in so I can navigate the project edit the code, build, and debug the app.  Hopefully it can parse the Cmake tree and find all the source files and header files for navigation and symbol searching.

The project is large, has quite a few subdirectories.  It builds fine from the command line and runs.

I see one needs to have the C++-Intellisense extestion installed, and the CMake Tools extension installed ( done )

Anyway want to open my "project" on A Macbook :)
Looking for help on this.
Thanks.

Comment: did you set [`"C_Cpp.default.configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference) yet?

Comment: If you are sure about there is nothing wrong with your project, you can simply press `command shift P`, input `CMake: Configure`, then it will start configuration for you.

Comment: will try that - this is a command for the VS code application I assume ?

Comment: @starball. nop don't know what that is.  I assume there are a "bunch of steps". I have to at least specify somewhere the CMakeLists.txt file at the root of the project and the build directory it outputs to ? than deal with (command shift P) and figure out what inputting "CMake: Configure) is  ( a popup dialog ? ) 

I am surprise there isn't a good "To Open and existing CMake based build tree" document out there that is found.

Comment: ... there is. plenty. you just failed to find it. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools#important-doc-links, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77079021/11107541