# Disable "Code analysis" in Visual Studio Code with C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile, code-analysis

(Note: this EDITed version is a truncated part of the original OP (kept at the bottom), after [this correct comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5bfL.png).
Two separate questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77399118/setup-make-build-tasks-with-externally-created-makefiles-in-visual-studio-code-w) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77399081/quick-navigation-between-a-list-of-compilation-errors-and-culprit-code-lines-in) were also posted. All this improves SO.)

I am slowly migrating from Eclipse CDT to VSCode with C/C++ Extension Pack.
I am working under Ubuntu 22, with g++.

When working in Eclipse, I am used to compiling/linking via g++ from within VSC, and getting a list of compilation errors.

Eclipse CDT has its own Code Analysis tool.
This tool "knows quite a bit" about C++ (although "much less" than the compiler) and produces further errors and warnings, *without compiling*, that add to the list above.
But it sometimes reports false positives, where there is nothing to fix (at least when compiling with g++).

To avoid these errors tainting the list, I can turn off CodeAn (I don't know if VSC lingo has a name for that).
Note that this still allows for quick-navigating *(error list)* -> *(code)*, it only removes error reporting by the Eclipse Code Analysis, keeping only *actual compilation* errors.

Below I am adding two images of the configuration menu in Eclipse. Scrolling down there are many other cases that can be detected by CodeAn.

**Can I perform this with VSCode?**
Note that I am referring to VSCode. Disabling CodeAn for VS might be different.

[image]

[image]

---

**Original question** (likely to be removed shortly to reduce the clutter)

I have a large C++ package, with its own CMake files.
Note that, when working at the command prompt, I use CMake to generate `makefile`s, and then compiling/linking with `make <flags> <target>`.
I don't use `cmake --build`, e.g.
When working in Eclipse, I am used to:

1. Setting up make targets so I compile/link with a double click.
2. Whenever a compilation error shows up, I can double click on the error in the list of errors to go straight to the line producing the error.

Eclipse CDT has its own Code Analysis tool.
This tool "knows quite a bit" about C++ (although "much less" than the compiler) and produces a list of errors and warnings, *without compiling*.
But it sometimes reports false positives, where there is nothing to fix (at least when compiling with g++).

3. To avoid these errors tainting the list, I can turn off CodeAn. Note that this still allows for navigating the code, it only removes error reporting by the Eclipse Code Analysis. These are two images of the configuration menu in Eclipse. Scrolling down there are many other cases that can be detected by CodeAn.

[IMAGES]

Can I perform #2 with VSCode?
I tried a few things for #1 (which is likely a prerequisite for #2), with json files, but I could not make it work.
**EDIT**: This question was split into [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77399081/quick-navigation-between-a-list-of-compilation-errors-and-culprit-code-lines-in). I will shortly adapt this OP.

Comment: Your title seems contradictory to what you're actually asking in the question. You want to disable VSC's debug/code analysis that comes with the MS C/C++ Extensions, but you want it to perform Code Analysis similar to Eclipse?

Comment: No. I want VSC **not** to perform any code analysis, the same as I ask Eclipse CDT (#3). 
All error reporting should come from the build process (i.e., g++), properly interfaced with the IDE.
If this interface works properly, navigation to *real* compilation error lines should be easy (#2).

Comment: I don't understand, why are you talking about (3) and code analysis at all? If your goal is, as stated in (2), to jump to errors from the build log, you just need to Alt+Click (the modifier can be different on your platform) the `filename:line` in the build log, and it will take you to that file and line.

Comment: Doesn't MS VS Project |> Properties |> Code Analysis allow you to disable it completely and/or configure which rules the MSC analyser will apply?

Comment: 1) what do you mean by "code navigation"? you mean things like "go to definition"? 2) I've edited my answer slightly 3) please add the link to your new question here.

Comment: @MartinBrown - I will check that setting, which I didn't find before. Note that I am using VSCode, not VS.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - You are correct. I have properly split this OP into separate, related questions, linked here. Your comment now refers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77399081/quick-navigation-between-a-list-of-compilation-errors-and-culprit-code-lines-in (and it could actually be an answer, I guess).
Thanks for pointing this out!
I would shortly remove these comments to reduce the clutter.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the only reason you want to disable error reporting from IntelliSense is to prevent them from being intermingled with the actual errors from the compiler? If so, simply removing the "problem matcher" from `tasks.json` (if you use that to run the build) would prevent the compilation errors from going into the "problems" tab, but you can still look at them (and quickly jump to the source location) from the terminal tab.

Comment: Site note: modern intellisense (talking primarily about Clangd, but maybe the stock MS one got better too) almost never disagrees with the compiler, when configured correctly.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - You are correct, that is my intention. I would check your suggestion, which could be an answer.
As for differences between the output of g++ compilation and Eclipse CodeAn, sometimes they could be annoying, with many (false) errors reported by CodeAn. Perhaps fine tuning its configuration, on a project-by-project basis, might help, but that would be too time consuming.

Comment: At least with Clangd, there's no manual configuration, you just feed the compiler flags for each source to it as a `compile_commands.json`. With that, Clangd should never disagree at least with Clang compiler. The stock intellisense should also understand that configuration format, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat your problem matcher suggestion is the opposite of what they want: "_To avoid these errors tainting the list, I can turn off CodeAn (I don't know if VSC lingo has a name for that). Note that this still allows for quick-navigating (error list) -> (code), it only removes error reporting by the Eclipse Code Analysis, keeping only actual compilation errors._" see also my answer post.

Comment: @starball An XY problem,  IMO. They don't want two types of errors in one list, so they disable one altogether, while instead they could have it in a separate tab. And they don't want false positive intrllisense errors, so they disable it altogether, instead of finding a better intellisense plugin and configuring it correctly.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - I don't want to taint the compilation error list with other false positives.
As you say, for me it's the same if I can have two separate lists or disable CodeAn for the intended purpose.
As for a better Intellisense, that would be a plus. I still wonder how any Intellisense/CodeAn could catch all *compilation* errors *without compiling*. I would (possibly lightly) think that it is impossible.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio At least Clangd doesn't diagnose *all* errors, some complex templates are not analyzed to save time. But there are normally no false positives. *"compilation errors without compiling"* Since it shares code with Clang the compiler, presumably it does something similar to first stages of compilation.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - No false positives is ok for me, much better than Eclipse CDT (I wouldn't know if it qualifies as "*modern*"). As for the specifics of CodeAn false positives, I could later provide examples.

Answer (score 1):

In case of CMake with the CMake Tools extension, (at least in my experience) the behaviour is already like that. You might find [my answer](/a/77079021/11107541) to [How can I set up C/C++ IntelliSense for a CMake project in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54671883/11107541) helpful.

Otherwise, just disable the Cpptools IntelliSense (`"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "disabled",` in settings.json) and use a build task with a [problem matcher](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_processing-task-output-with-problem-matchers) such as the provided `$gcc` one. Even without a problem matcher, the integrated terminal in VS Code [supports several common file+line patterns](/q/77184537/11107541) and will make those patterns into links that you can click into when holding down your link modifier (typically <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd> or <kbd>alt/opt</kbd>).

Comment: As mentioned in comment above, and further clarified in edited OP, when working at the command prompt I use CMake to generate `makefile`s, and then compiling/linking with `make <flags> <target>`.
I don't use `cmake --build`, e.g.
So in practice my use of cmake (and the CMake Tools extension) is irrelevant.
I would still like to have IntelliSense features, which has nothing to do with CMake; I don't understand why not using CMake would amount to disabling IntelliSense.
I will try to learn how to setup all this, with make targets.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio If you're using CMake, IMO it's a waste not to use CMake Tools. And even if you insist not to use CMake tools for some odd reason, I don't see why not use `cmake --build`. The IntelliSense _does_ have to do with CMake, because if you want to get it in VS Code when building with CMake, the most common and easy way is to use the CMake Tools extension and configure the intellisense provider as described in the linked Q&A.

Comment: Not using `cmake --build` was simply an "inherited" procedure in a large project, and I never bothered changing that. If I were to start from scratch I would probably do so, and I might in the future.