# VSCode Why is active code show as inactive in C++ OpenGL project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to understand a C++ OpenGL project (github/XCSoar) using VSCode on a Debian Linux box (don't think that is significant, but...).  I have noticed that the 'active/inactive' code block highlighting is wrong sometimes, and it really screws up my understanding of what is going on.

Here is a screenshot of a section of code where the program has halted in debug mode, in the middle of a code block that has been marked as 'inactive' (I edited the C++ Extensions setting to make the 'inactive code block' designation obvious).[image: VS Code 'inactive block' that is clearly 'active']

Any idea why this is happening?  The 'ENABLE_OPENGL' symbol isn't defined or declared, at least according to VSCode, but the program is certainly an OPENGL app, and stepping through the code definitely steps through the 'inactive' block.

TIA,

Frank

Comment: The syntax highlighting has it's own parser, and is done independently of the compiler.  If VSCode and your project are set up right, the highlighting parser with jibe with the compiler.  If not set up correctly... what you are seeing is the result.

Comment: how is the value of the macro `ENABLE_OPENGL` specified? Is it specified earlier in the translation unit in the implementation source file or by an included header? or is it supposed to be specified at compile-time via compile flag? if the latter, then look at `defines` in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference

Comment: How have you configured intellisense? Its configuration needs to match your compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out `compilerArgs` in [c_cpp_properties.json reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference), just add the preprocessor definition, add the following inside of your project [Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_workspace-settings) (`.vscode/settings.json`):

```
"C_Cpp.default.compilerArgs": [
    "-DENABLE_OPENGL",
    "-DHAVE_DYNAMIC_MULTI_DRAW_ARRAYS"
]
```

There's not much workaround regarding this, you'll probably need to add more definitions based on the compiler args you have in the project.

Comment: Thanks to everyone - that makes a lot of sense, and I'll definitely go through the settings

Comment: Manually configuring intellisense should be a last resort. Most build systems have a vscode plugin that can do that for you automatically

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I personally don't have much experience with GNU Makefiles and its vscode extension, if you could share us the automatic configuration for GNU Makefiles like how CMake (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71115284/19336104) does, then that'll be great!

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.makefile-tools