CMake language IntelliSense for VS Code
I want to have IntelliSense and auto-complete for all CMake/CMakeLists.txt files.
I have tried installing the CMake VS Code extensions, but it is working only for the default CMake functions like, project(), add_library(), target_link_libraries(), etc. But I am trying to understand if I can somehow detect all the CMake functions available in the system (all packages) or specific packages configured with some paths. say for example ament_cmake packages or catkin packages. I couldn't find these settings in CMake extension.

for anyone looking for intellisense for a programming language that their project builds using CMake, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/54671883/11107541

VS Code doesn't provide a builtin language-support extension for the CMake language. CMake Tools doesn't really do CMake language support (it focuses more on config, build, run, and debug). So that leaves other extensions in the marketplace. I've used two of them before: twxs.cmake and josetr.cmake-language-support-vscode (I have no affiliation with any of the CMake extensions in the marketplace). I find that josetr.cmake-language-support-vscode is a little better in terms of language-support feature coverage, and last I recall, a little more ahead in supporting newer CMake features, but still definitely lagging the latest releases. twxs.cmake does not seem to be in active development anymore, but josetr.cmake-language-support-vscode is not open source. It's a bit of an unfortunate reality. You have a couple choices: keep looking (for alternative in the extension marketplace), keep patiently hoping and waiting for the maintainers of existing extensions to keep improving their extensions (search for existing issue tickets, and raise one if you have a new feature-request or found a new bug), or go be the change and help develop those extensions, or build your own.
